# XML with multiple tags

Tags: python, xml, csv, beautifulsoup

Problem is parsing through an xml that starts right after `<Envelope>`

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
Filename =input("Enter File name to be imported :" )
imp_ext = ".xml"
imp_file = ("".join([Filename,imp_ext]))
#it is in UTF-16BE format
with open(imp_file, encoding= 'UTF-16') as fp:  
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'xml')
```

Soup has this data:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ENVELOPE>
   <DSPACCNAME>
      <DSPDISPNAME>206375</DSPDISPNAME>
   </DSPACCNAME>
   <DSPSTKINFO>
      <DSPSTKOUT>
         <DSPOUTQTY>1 EA</DSPOUTQTY>
         <DSPOUTRATE>715.00</DSPOUTRATE>
         <DSPNETTCRAMTA>715.00</DSPNETTCRAMTA>
         <DSPCRAMTA>715.00</DSPCRAMTA>
         <DSPCONSAMT>-358.62</DSPCONSAMT>
         <DSPGPAMT>356.38</DSPGPAMT>
         <DSPGPPERC>49.84 %</DSPGPPERC>
      </DSPSTKOUT>
      <DSPSTKCL>
         <DSPCLQTY>3 EA</DSPCLQTY>
         <DSPCLRATE>358.62</DSPCLRATE>
         <DSPCLAMTA>-1075.87</DSPCLAMTA>
      </DSPSTKCL>
   </DSPSTKINFO>
   <SSBATCHNAME>
      <SSBATCH />
      <SSGODOWN>Ware -House (Mankoli-Bhiwandi)</SSGODOWN>
   </SSBATCHNAME>
   <DSPSTKINFO>
      <DSPSTKOUT>
         <DSPOUTQTY>1 EA</DSPOUTQTY>
         <DSPOUTRATE>715.00</DSPOUTRATE>
         <DSPNETTCRAMTA>715.00</DSPNETTCRAMTA>
         <DSPCRAMTA>715.00</DSPCRAMTA>
         <DSPCONSAMT>-358.62</DSPCONSAMT>
         <DSPGPAMT>356.38</DSPGPAMT>
         <DSPGPPERC>49.84 %</DSPGPPERC>
      </DSPSTKOUT>
      <DSPSTKCL>
         <DSPCLQTY>3 EA</DSPCLQTY>
         <DSPCLRATE>358.62</DSPCLRATE>
         <DSPCLAMTA>-1075.87</DSPCLAMTA>
      </DSPSTKCL>
   </DSPSTKINFO>
</ENVELOPE>
```

then I am trying to extract data from xml file
I also tried:

```py
for a in soup.findAll('DSPACCNAME'):
    for b in soup.findAll('DSPSTKINFO'):
        print(a.DSPDISPNAME)
        print(b.DSPCLQTY)
        print(b.DSPCLRATE)
        print(b.DSPCLAMTA)
```

I am getting output that is something like this:

206375

1 EA

715.00

715.00

715.00

-358.62

356.38

49.84 %

Issue is I don't have a parent class that creates a boundary. I am trying to extract the data in CSV format. Data comes from tally. It is called stock summary to be exact. I have no idea how to proceed. Data comes with empty values as well. And that needs to be captured as it is.

edit* : I am purposefully putting a part of xml that has all the data needed to be extracted (row 13 of image is the expected output). Output needs to be something that has all these values, with lowest level granularity(Every thing in 1 row) please have a look at this image for reference:

[image]

Comment: Based on the xml you have posted - what is the expected output?

Comment: Well, even though it says UTF-8, however, sometimes there are BOM that causes python to give empty "soup"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I summarize my proposal for a solution with the SAX-parser, which is very performant, but its structure takes a bit of effort for the tuning of the needed results.

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70437073/xml-with-multiple-tags
from collections import OrderedDict
from xml.sax.handler import ContentHandler
import xml.sax
import sys

class CustomHandler(ContentHandler):
    def __init__( self ):
        tmp = ["DSPACCNAME", "DSPSTKOUT", "DSPSTKCL"] # extensible with further tags
        self.tags = OrderedDict()
        for t in tmp:
            self.tags.setdefault(t, False)

    def startElement(self, name, attrs):
        if name in self.tags.keys():
            self.tags[name] = True
            sys.stdout.write("\n%s\n%15s\n" % (name.strip(), "="*15))

    def characters(self, content):
        for v  in self.tags.values():
            if v:
                sys.stdout.write("%3s" % content.strip())

    def endElement(self, name):
        if name in self.tags.keys():
            self.tags[name] = False 

parser = xml.sax.make_parser()
handler = CustomHandler()
parser.setContentHandler(handler)
parser.parse("test.xml")
```

```
RESULTS: 

DSPACCNAME
===============
      206375      
DSPSTKOUT
===============
      1 EA      715.00      715.00      715.00      -358.62      356.38      49.84 %      
DSPSTKCL
===============
      3 EA      358.62      -1075.87      
DSPSTKOUT
===============
      1 EA      715.00      715.00      715.00      -358.62      356.38      49.84 %      
DSPSTKCL
===============
      3 EA      358.62      -1075.87
```

Comment: You are a pure genius! It's working like a charm!  A little bit far from what I wanted so I'm working on that, but, Yes it working perfectly!

Comment: Also, I am very Interested in learning it (SAX-parser). I have recently started learning coding. I am still learning Objects and Classes. Please do suggest any links will help me do things better. Thank you.

Comment: I have added the output image of what values I want in a CSV file, It will have some headers as well. I normally make multiple lists pertaining to each column, initialise it with a string that makes the header, and then keep appending the values in it. Then zip everything together and extract it in csv file. I did try it by making a dictionary, however, it was not including the empty spaces. So, I started using list as I found it more flexible. However, I know using dictionary will be much more efficient and pythonic.

Comment: Hi @AlokPandey, i would recommend you the following resources, which have been very usefull for me : https://www.python-kurs.eu/python_XML_SAX.php and and The Cookbook from Alex Martelli / Chapter 12 (I have the one, which considers Python 2, but it should be ok), for sure the python docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.sax.html#module-xml.sax are also a good place to start :)

Comment: The first link is unfortunatelly only in german, but the code blocks are very good structured and providing a lot of understanding of the mechanics of the sax-parser

Comment: Thank you I will look into it. Coming to the solution you provided, I am not sure how to efficiently convert it into a csv format. There are some values missing in xml data, which is needed to be captured as it is by a blank space. I think in your code, those are tagged as False with variable v. I went as far as to extract individual tags as it was returning multiple output. It was working fine until it encountered an empty value. I Would appreciate if you can guide me on that. My email is alokpandey0903@gmail.com

Comment: You could try to skip the values, which are black with a check of the content aganinst ""-empty : if content !="" : (...make something...)

Comment: I tried doing that but it is not giving me what I want. for instance 
DSPACCNAME
===============
      206375         
DSPSTKOUT
===============
      1 EA      715.00      715.00      715.00      -358.62      356.38      49.84 %   
DSPSTKCL
===============
      3 EA      358.62      -1075.87   
SSBATCHNAME
===============
            Ware -House (Mankoli-Bhiwandi) Here, there are suppose to be 2 values in SSBATCHNAME but one is missing. When I try to add a it to list it completely ignores that slot itself.

Comment: To understand what might be happening I tried returning list of strings separated by "\n" instead of strings. I got  
 SSBATCH
===============

SSGODOWN
===============
['Ware -House (Mankoli-Bhiwandi)'].   It seems there does not exist any value at all. So tried doing something like if content==None: print(" ") but it is also not capturing that.

Comment: What would be your approach if this data is to be extracted in a csv file? where every column has 1 tag. If multiple entries are present it should be in another row. I am trying to read the documentation to reach a solution. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240333/discussion-between-baskettaz-and-alok-pandey).

Comment: I would prefer to organize all the data in dictionary with key the DSPACCNAME and value list of lists, where the number of the lists will be dependant from the recurring DSPSTKOUT - tag for example under your parent tag. This will be very beneficial if you know that the number of tags will always be the same independently from the content e.g. d[DSPACCNAME] = [[DSPSTKOUT1], ..., [DSPSTKOUT_N]], in this manner you will be able later to write this data structure to your csv-file very easy. The trap here is the KEY == DSPACCNAME, which will overwrite the last entry in not unique ...